# How to change background color of table cell while using Bootstrap's CSS classes?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap 5.0 CSS and am trying to make a table with custom cell colors using some of my own CSS. The `color` property works fine, but when I try to change the background color using the `background` property, Bootstrap ignores the rule. Does anyone know how to fix this?

My code:

```css
td.colorfy {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td class="colorfy">cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I suggest reading [the documentation for tables](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/tables/) as there is information there regarding how background colors are calculated. You may want to use one of the Bootstrap classes to make the change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the `!important` directive to override any other behavior set by bootstrap. Have a look [here](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-the-important-property-in-css) for more information.

```css
td.colorfy {
    background: blue !important;
    color: white;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td class="colorfy">cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or be more specific when setting your css rule:

```css
.table td.colorfy {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td class="colorfy">cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As in bootstrap css the color is specified as:

```
.table>:not(caption)>*>* {
    padding: .5rem .5rem;
    background-color: var(--bs-table-bg);
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 9999px var(--bs-table-accent-bg)
}
```

and that is more specific then your definition, it wins. By be more specific as bootstrap or using `!important` you can achieve the new background color.

Comment: Note what that site says: "all subsequent definitions for this property will be ignored". So if you later want to change, say, the background image for the row, the `!important` in this answer will override that.

Comment: My real code has a lot of rules, and I'd prefer not to manually add `!important` to all of them.

Comment: then use the more specific definition i just added